# Web conferencing software or service with Linux support

Tags: linux, sharing, video-conferencing

I'm a Linux Mint user and currently use WebEx for hosting web demos with audio conferencing capabilities. I pay for their monthly service; however, I'm forced to use Windows to do both VoIP audio and desktop sharing reliably. I've tried various solutions to allow WebEx to do audio and desktop/app sharing with Mint and Windows without much success. My requirements:

1. Must have audio conferencing capabilities with ability to use VoIP or a provided dial in number
2. Must be able to do desktop/app sharing from a Linux host
3. Should have good reliable performance. Service doesn't have to be free (I'm using the WebEx $20/month plan.

My guests will be running Windows or Macintosh, and best if the solution doesn't require Flash and shouldn't require cumbersome installation of plugins. Prefer it is NOT Java based.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Zoom.us](https://zoom.us).

My experience with it is all through [Glip](https://glip.com/), but:

- On the home page, Zoom claims to support the Linux desktop (as well as Mac OS X and Windows)
- Assuming it acts the same on all platforms, you can do audio- or video-chatting, and even share and remotely control other screens
- When Glip launches a Zoom call, it provides a dial-in number
- Zoom [also claims](https://zoom.us/roomconnector) that you can join a room using things like H.323 and SIP.
- Zoom has [different plans](https://zoom.us/pricing), and it looks like you can use it a bit for free.
- Lastly, when Glip launches a Zoom connection, it offers to have you install something -- I think it is a stand-alone app and not a plugin -- and it only takes a couple of minutes, one time.  After that, calls only take, say, 30 seconds to initiate.  I do not believe it uses Flash or Java.